# What is Difference between Virtual Method call and Direct Method call in context of VTable?

Tags: c++

What is difference between Virtual Method call and Direct Method call in context of VTable ?
How the Method reference is resolved in case of Virtual & Direct Call ?

Comment: Has nothing to do with C, I removed the tag.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, no such thing exists, the C++ standard does not define it (virtual calls are defined, but it is not specified how they must work, no such thing as a VTable exists).

In practice, a virtual call *does* use a vtable on every compiler that I know about. This is a memory overhead of one table of addresses per class that has virtual members (per class, **not** per instance!) and one pointer to that table per instance.
A virtual call is -- depending on architecture -- either a load from that table followed by a call to the loaded address, or a so-called indirect call (which is the same, but in one instruction).

A direct call is just a plain normal function call (single instruction) to an address that the compiler knows (there exist some exceptions with shared library calls, which may use indirect and even double-indirect calls as well). Whenever the compiler is 100% certain about an object's runtime type or when you explicitly tell it via scope resolution (`operator::`), that's what is used.

The big difference between direct and indirect calls has traditionally been branch prediction and pipelining, making indirect calls *much* more expensive (10-15 times), but more recent CPUs implement this equally well for either case (there is a dedicated indirect call cache on modern CPUs).
I won't go as far as saying the difference is non-existent or neglegible, but it sure is no biggie nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

A class with virtual methods defined will add a hidden pointer member to the class. The pointer points to what is called the V-table, which is a block of function pointers that correspond to the virtual methods for the class.

Each class that derives from a class with virtual methods inherits this hidden pointer member. However, in addition, each such class will have its own V-table. So, instantiations of the derived class will initialize this pointer to it's own V-table.

This way, when calling a virtual method on a base class with virtual methods, when it consults the V-table pointer, that pointer is actually pointing to a derived class's table, This is how calling a virtual method from the base will actually invoke the derived class's implementation. So, a compiler when encountering a virtual method resolves the call with this code that does the lookup through the V-table pointer.

A direct method call has no V-table lookup code. The compiler simply resolves the call to the address of a function that corresponds to the method.