# Is a vtable lookup performed when indirectly calling a virtual method in a non-overridden base method from a derived immediate object?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, vtable

This question is a slightly more convoluted version of the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584670/direct-vs-virtual-call-to-a-virtual-function) which has been very well answered.
In the semantics used in the answer, I'm referring to the *implementation level* of the virtual call (i.e. typically a vtable lookup).

A base class implements a member (typically non virtual) using a virtual member, overridden in some derived class. When using a *derived immediate object* (no pointer or reference involved) to call this member, is there a vtable lookup involved?

Here is the most simplified scenario I came up with:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    void generic_method()
    {
        // Do some stuff
        specialized_method();
    }

    virtual void specialized_method(); // Details are useless here.
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void specialized_method() override;
};

int main()
{
    // I don't want neither need type resolution at runtime.
    // Using the immediate object
    B b;

    // Is there a vtable lookup for the indirect `specialized_method` call here?
    b.generic_method();
}
```

Every type involved *can be resolved at compile time*. Therefore, I'm expecting a direct call in that case, but am I somehow preventing such an optimization?

#### More context

I don't like to rely on a compiler optimization for my usecase.
Here is what I'm trying to achieve.
Any suggestion is of course welcome.

- The `generic_method` is an algorithm.
- This relies on the initialization of some container. Here I want the user to be totally free in how to set each value. But I want to guarantee the structure of the container to be valid.
- I would therefore initialize the structure - which is not trivial - in the mother class, and let the user override the function returning each value (`specific_method` in the code) to fill the container. It will be used for every container entry.
- This container is typically very big, and the specific method is very fast, so the virtual call overhead is relevant.

What I thought about:

- Do not rely on inheritance and use a lambda expression as argument. But `this` would not be captured and I don't want to change the access specifiers.
- I could give the responsibility of initializing this container to the constructor of every child class. But I cannot enforce that, or make it really explicit in the code: I would have to rely on documentation to give the incentive to the programmer-user to initialize the container in the secure way I want.
- Would the use of a pure virtual method as the specialized method enforce the resolution of the type at compile time and prevent the vtable lookup?
- Use the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (CRTP) to implement a static polymorphism.

Comment: Are you asking whether there will be a vtable lookup for the `specialized_method()` call inside of `generic_method()`?

Comment: Can you edit [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64808615/edit)?

Comment: @Kevin Thank you I could clarify the question. And yes this is exactly what I mean.

Comment: In the question I'm referring to, the answer explains that if I would call the `specialized_method` directly from the `b` object, there shouldn't be a vtable lookup.

Comment: Maybe a way to achieve the original goal is to use the so called _Curiously recurring template pattern_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: @prapin Yes I considered it and another user pointed it out in a (now deleted) comment. I will add it to the "what I thought about" list.
If I implement it that way, I will post it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `A::generic_method`: since `specialized_method();` is really `this->specialized_method();` this will do a dynamic binding (e.g. vtable lookup).

`B::generic_method` is inherited from A so `b.generic_method()` is a static binding to `A::generic_method` (and inside this call there is the dynamic binding of `specialized_method` I've talked above)

Modern compilers can optimize and skip the vtable lookup completely if they can "see" the real type of the object (the optimization is called devirtualization). gcc performed devirtualization in all my tests, while (to my surprise) clang wasn't able in most cases.

All tests on gcc 10.2 and clang 11.0.0 with `-O3`.

## Situation: no virtual destructor

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/T1hKx7)

### Case 1: the vtable lookup can be skipped

```
auto t1()
{
    B b{};
    b.generic_method();
}

auto t2(B b)
{
    b.generic_method();
}
```

For `t1` both gcc and clang skip the vtable lookup and directly call `B::specialized_method()`. For `t2` only gcc performs the optimization:

gcc output:

```
t1():
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], OFFSET FLAT:_ZTV1B+16
        lea     rdi, [rsp+8]
        call    B::specialized_method()
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
t2(B):
        jmp     B::specialized_method()
```

Clang output

```
t1():                                 # @t1()
        push    rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], offset vtable for B+16
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    B::specialized_method()
        pop     rax
        ret
t2(B):                                # @t2(B)
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        jmp     qword ptr [rax]                 # TAILCALL
```

### Case 2: the binding must be dynamic, cannot be devirtualized:

```
auto t3(B& b)
{
    b.generic_method();
}

auto t4(B* b)
{
    b->generic_method();
}
```

```
t3(B&):                               # @t3(B&)
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        jmp     qword ptr [rax]                 # TAILCALL
t4(B*):                               # @t4(B*)
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        jmp     qword ptr [rax]                 # TAILCALL
```

## Situation: virtual destructor

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/66hqna)

### Case 1: the vtable lookup can be skipped

```
auto t1()
{
    B b{};
    b.generic_method();
}

auto t2(B b)
{
    b.generic_method();
}

auto t5()
{
    std::unique_ptr<B> b = std::make_unique<B>();
    b->generic_method();
}


auto t6()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> b = std::make_unique<B>();
    b->generic_method();
}

auto t7()
{
    B* b = new B{};
    b->generic_method();
    delete b;
}

auto t8()
{
    A* b = new B{};
    b->generic_method();
    delete b;
}
```

Gcc performs devirtualization for all examples, while clang for none:

Gcc output:

```
t1():
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], OFFSET FLAT:_ZTV1B+16
        lea     rdi, [rsp+8]
        call    B::specialized_method()
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
t2(B):
        jmp     B::specialized_method()
t5():
        push    r12
        mov     edi, 8
        push    rbp
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], OFFSET FLAT:_ZTV1B+16
        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     rbp, rax
        call    B::specialized_method()
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp+0]
        mov     rdi, rbp
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+16]
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        jmp     rax
        mov     r12, rax
        jmp     .L8
t5() [clone .cold]:
.L8:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp+0]
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    [QWORD PTR [rax+16]]
        mov     rdi, r12
        call    _Unwind_Resume
t6():
        push    r12
        mov     edi, 8
        push    rbp
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], OFFSET FLAT:_ZTV1B+16
        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     rbp, rax
        call    B::specialized_method()
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp+0]
        mov     rdi, rbp
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+16]
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        jmp     rax
        mov     r12, rax
        jmp     .L12
t6() [clone .cold]:
.L12:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp+0]
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    [QWORD PTR [rax+16]]
        mov     rdi, r12
        call    _Unwind_Resume
t7():
        push    rbp
        mov     edi, 8
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], OFFSET FLAT:_ZTV1B+16
        mov     rbp, rax
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    B::specialized_method()
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp+0]
        mov     rdi, rbp
        pop     rbp
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+16]
        jmp     rax
t8():
        push    rbp
        mov     edi, 8
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], OFFSET FLAT:_ZTV1B+16
        mov     rbp, rax
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    B::specialized_method()
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp+0]
        mov     rdi, rbp
        pop     rbp
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+16]
        jmp     rax
```

clang output:

```
t1():                                 # @t1()
        push    rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], offset vtable for B+16
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    qword ptr [rip + vtable for B+16]
        pop     rax
        ret
t2(B):                                # @t2(B)
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        jmp     qword ptr [rax]                 # TAILCALL

t5():                                 # @t5()
        push    r14
        push    rbx
        push    rax
        mov     edi, 8
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     rbx, rax
        mov     qword ptr [rax], offset vtable for B+16
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    qword ptr [rip + vtable for B+16]
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rbx]
        mov     rdi, rbx
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     r14
        jmp     qword ptr [rax + 16]            # TAILCALL
        mov     r14, rax
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rbx]
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    qword ptr [rax + 16]
        mov     rdi, r14
        call    _Unwind_Resume
t6():                                 # @t6()
        push    r14
        push    rbx
        push    rax
        mov     edi, 8
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     rbx, rax
        mov     qword ptr [rax], offset vtable for B+16
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    qword ptr [rip + vtable for B+16]
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rbx]
        mov     rdi, rbx
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     r14
        jmp     qword ptr [rax + 16]            # TAILCALL
        mov     r14, rax
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rbx]
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    qword ptr [rax + 16]
        mov     rdi, r14
        call    _Unwind_Resume
t7():                                 # @t7()
        push    rbx
        mov     edi, 8
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     rbx, rax
        mov     qword ptr [rax], offset vtable for B+16
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    qword ptr [rip + vtable for B+16]
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rbx]
        mov     rdi, rbx
        pop     rbx
        jmp     qword ptr [rax + 16]            # TAILCALL
t8():                                 # @t8()
        push    rbx
        mov     edi, 8
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     rbx, rax
        mov     qword ptr [rax], offset vtable for B+16
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    qword ptr [rip + vtable for B+16]
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rbx]
        mov     rdi, rbx
        pop     rbx
        jmp     qword ptr [rax + 16]            # TAILCALL
```

## Case 2: the binding must be dynamic, cannot be devirtualized:

```
auto t3(B& b)
{
    b.generic_method();
}

auto t4(B* b)
{
    b->generic_method();
}
```

```
t3(B&):                               # @t3(B&)
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        jmp     qword ptr [rax]                 # TAILCALL
t4(B*):                               # @t4(B*)
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        jmp     qword ptr [rax]                 # TAILCALL
```

Comment: Thank you for your extensive analysis.
So the specific case of my question corresponds to your `t1` case: simply using a virtual destructor (fairly common!) prevents the devirtualization optimization for clang on which I'm relying for performance... Definitely not the way to go!

Comment: @jmon12  Yo are welcome. Yes, `t1` and I was surprised at the clang results.

Answer (score 2):

The `generic_method()` function has an implicit `A* const this` parameter, so you're wrong that there is *no pointer or reference involved*. The body of the function has no knowledge of who's calling it, so it needs to make a vtable lookup to figure out which `specialized_method()` function to call.

Imagine `A` is defined in some library, and I write a new `C` class that derives from `A`. How would the library, which has already been compiled and is just being linked into my program, know that it needs to call `C::specialized_method()`?

A compiler could in theory have enough knowledge to know that `generic_method()` is only ever called on a `B` object, or it could inline `generic_method()` for every call, but you shouldn't rely on that. It's also unlikely that it would be able to do that out in anything but the simplest examples.

Comment: The whole thing is inlined here: https://godbolt.org/z/E66ecY . Though whether he should rely on that is another matter...

Comment: I admit that relying on that is clumsy. But still in the case "library + `C` derived class" you mention, if I use a derived **immediate object** (e.g. of type `C`) to call `generic_method`, then the compiler will _always_ have the necessary information to resolve the right `specified_method` to use at compile time. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jmon12 It's probably inlining the `generic_method()` call, so is able to avoid the vtable lookup. With complicated enough code it won't be able to do that.

Comment: Yes, it is inlining because it has the necessary information to do so, and should have it for any derived type used as an immediate object, at least in that simple case. But you're anyway right, I shouldn't rely on that.

Comment: @Artefacto In your test, you make the virtual method `specialized_method` pure virtual. Can it have an impact on the compiler's behavior? I'm sorry I'm not that handy enough with this compiler explorer tool and with machine code to really answer this question myself...

Comment: @Artefacto OK I ran your test again, and having a pure virtual or virtual method doesn't change anything. And the inlining is performed for the `-O1` optimization flag.

Comment: There was an interesting answer which was removed too quickly for me to entirely read it. If this candidate doesn't show up, I will accept your answer. Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: I also liked the other answer that was here for a bit. It looked like compilers were unable (in some cases?) to remove the virtual call if there was a virtual destructor. Maybe it will be back?

Comment: Looks like it's back

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224487/discussion-between-jmon12-and-kevin).